# Connect Webpack 5 Module Federation to a non NodeJs App

Tags: webpack, frontend

I have been testing some examples of Webpack 5 Module Federation and works just fine for me!
[Here it is an example](https://github.com/mizx/mfe-webpack-demo).

However, I have been trying to connect it to a different Host. In the project that I work on, we have a huge legacy app that works with Play Framework 1.4.3, the app has 5 year old already and we do not have the time(money) to completely redo on modern React (I really wish).

So that I have create some small micro react apps and injected in the HTML.
`<script src="/public/reactJS/app.bundle.js"></script>`
Thats work but it is a big hack and will be harder and harder to maintain as it grows.

Therefore my question is how do I connect a this module federation in a old App using different language (Java), is that even possible?